# Patching object with Gorm. Initial NULL integer is now 0

Tags: go, go-gorm

I am patching a row in Postgres DB with Gorm:

```
type Meter struct {
    ID            string `json:"id" gorm:"primary_key;column:id_meter"`
    OperationID   uint   `json:"operation_id,omitempty" gorm:"column:id_operation"`
    Pack          uint   `json:"pack,omitempty" gorm:"column:pack"`
}


func PatchMeter(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    w.Header().Set("Content-Type", "application/json")
    db := SetupDB()
    defer db.Close()
    var meter models.Meter
    s, _ := ioutil.ReadAll(r.Body)
    err = json.Unmarshal(s, &meter)
    db.Save(&meter)
}
```

The body I send in my PATCH request is:

```
{ "id": "55",
  "operation_id": 8,
  "pack": "",
}
```

Thing is pack has a default to NULL, and having pack 0 is very different from having pack `NULL`

As parsing between value and uint field is "automatic", I don't see how can I make a difference between 0 and NULL in DB.

Comment: This is unrelated but do not ignore the error, you can't unmarshal `"pack": ""` into `Pack uint`, one is a string the other an integer, please be diligent.

Comment: You can use `*uint` for nilable fields and then in your json you can use the `null` keyword, or omit the field altogether. Then, although I don't use gorm so I can't be sure but, I assume a `nil` field will be sent as `NULL` to the db.

Comment: Yes, I tried it, but I think I won't use Gorm. ORM is supposed to save time, not the opposite

Comment: @Juliatzin I don't think that is the problem of Gorm, it is not possible to make a difference between Null and 0  using `uint`  https://tour.golang.org/basics/12